# Как преобразовать массив в формат json?

Tags: json, php

В формат вида:

```
[{"title": "test", "value": "test"}]
```

Массив вида:

```
$['language'][] = array("title" => $value, "value" => $key);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[json_encode](http://php.ru/manual/function.json-encode.html)

P.S. Не забудь в функции сделать **echo** json_encode($['language']);

Comment: Так пробовал, если в массиве несколько элементов, то получаю:

`{"1":{"title":"\u043c\u043e\u043b\u0434\u0430\u0432\u0441\u043a\u0438\u0439","value":27}}`
____

Если в массиве несколько элементов, нужно разделить их запятой по шаблону, как указано в шаблоне, в итоге должна получиться строка.
____
Пришлось сделать так:

`foreach ($language as $key => $value) {
     $this->data['data']['languageArray'][] = '{"title" : "'.$value.'", "value" : "'.$key.'"}';
    } $this->data['data']['languageArray'] = '['.implode(', ', $this->data['data']['languageArray']).']';`

Comment: 1. Ребят, вы уверены что `$['language']` - это вообще валидное обращение к перменной?
2. Очень похоже на то, что кто-то проставил строковый ключ "1" массиву. У меня всё работает.

Comment: @Etki, вот жесть... как углядел?)

Comment: @Автостопом_до_Рая, просто я великолепный сам по себе.